# __declspec(dllexport) while importing. Does not seem to make a difference?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, dllimport, dllexport

Let me begin by saying, I know what the purpose of the `__declspec(dllexport)` keyword is. But experimenting for the sake of it, when importing functions with this keyword vs when not using the keyword, I don't see any difference in the import/export table of the EXE that gets generated.

To illustrate, I have a DLL project that includes a header file with the following declaration:

`__declspec(dllexport) int somefunc(int, int)`

And then another project that builds an EXE importing functions from the DLL:

```
#include "path_to_header_file_of_dll"
int main() {
    somefunc();
}
```

When I build this EXE, it seems to compile and build fine even though I have declared the function as exporting that symbol, when it is clearly not exporting it, only importing it. Why doesn't the compiler complain? Also this doesn't cause the generated EXE to have an export table. But builds an import table instead. The compiler seems to have figured out the correct thing to do and does it.

If this works, then why bother with code like this below:

```
#ifdef BLEH
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLLEXPORT int somefunc(int, int);
```

Comment: I would have expected it to re-export the function after importing it, but apparently there's another step that comes in and says "No, that's silly" and pretends it never happened. That said, you're importing the function using the stub rather than the import directly since it is not marked dllimport, so it's still not a great idea. The point of the dllimport is to bypass the stub.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you link some reference to what is in that stub. I keep reading about the stub in different answers, but I don't think I have seen any reading material on it.

Comment: @Frankie_C MSVC compiler.

Comment: You can see the stub for yourself by stepping into the disassembly. It varies from architecture to architecture, but the goal is to make a function in another module appear to be local. For x86, the stub is an indirect jump through the iat.

Comment: @RaymondChen With `Whole Program Optimization` enabled, the disassembly does not show any difference between the code generated with `__declspec(dllimport)` and the code generated without it. With `Whole Program Optimization` disabled, I can see the difference. However, the effect of this setting on `__declspec(dllimport)` does not seem to be documented anywhere.